# How can we get the url of any record using TransactionSearchAdvanced using java

Tags: suitetalk

I want to get NetSuite URL of a record using saved search in java suite talk

This is a java script code of Transaction Search, I have to convert it into Suite talk using java. I am able to get internalid, account, entity etc but i am not able to get link for each record. How can i get the link?

util.each(searchResults, function (row) {

```
            var obj = {
                id: row.internalid,
                linkText: row.account,
                link: commons.resolveRecordUrl('invoice', row.internalid),
                text: ' | ' + row.entity + ' | ' + self.formatMoney(row.amount) + ' | ' + row.trandate
            };
            // log.debug({ title: "obj", details: obj });
            results.push(obj);
        });
```

Comment: Add more details regarding your problem, show us some code and highlight the issue

Comment: var obj = {
                    id: row.internalid,
                    linkText: row.account,
                    link: commons.resolveRecordUrl('invoice', row.internalid),
                    text: ' | ' + row.entity + ' | ' + self.formatMoney(row.amount) + ' | ' + row.trandate
                };

Comment: how can convert this into suitetalk ->       link: commons.resolveRecordUrl('invoice', row.internalid)